# Create guided tour in an Android app

Tags: android

I want to create interactive tour in my app like this:

[image]

How can i achieve it? Do you know a library to make it easier?

Comment: Viewpager with your own screenshots would probarbly be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView) probably is your best option. It's designed to highlight and showcase specific parts of apps to the user with a distinctive and attractive overlay. The library is great for pointing out points of interest of users, gestures, or obscure but useful items.

The library is based on the 'Cling' View found in the Launcher on ICS and Jelly Bean, but extended to be easier to use.

GitHub repository [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can check this one [link](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/6cVymZvn3f4). Here Roman Nurik created a wizard which can be used as your purpose by some modification. You can see the source [here](https://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/source/browse/misc/wizardpager#wizardpager/src/com/example/android/wizardpager/wizard).

But I think it is better to create your own guided tour. Create it using Fragments and ViewPager.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using this library in your application: [Showcase View](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView). It is based on the `View` that Android shows in ICS and JB when you start a fresh device for the first time / factory reset / flash, say CM 10 / 10.1. As also the app launcher when *launched* for the first time.

*EDIT: This is how it looks*

[image]

And as pointed out by *Warpzit* in his comment, *in theory* (I haven't used is so far, but am really keen on using it soon), you could use the library with screenshots in a `ViewPager`.

There is an Open Source project on Github called [TweetLanes](https://github.com/chrislacy/TweetLanes) which uses a similar approach (minus the library mentioned above). You could download and give the source a look to see how the app implements.  And as mentioned, it's Open Source. ;-)