# Display overlay tooltip on the first run

Tags: android, user-interface

When run for the first time (or after some major update), some Google apps or the core Android system itself sometimes display a transparent overlay with a short tooltip how to use the new features. An example might be the image bellow.

Is there some API in the Android framework for creating these or is it all custom made? How would one implement it in latter case? And last, but not least, do these tooltips have some kind of an official/technical name by which one can refer to them (might be useful when Googling for some info about the subject)? Thanks.

**Edit**

I've acquired a screenshot which illustrates more precisely what I mean. Apart from the "pointing hand" graphic, this tooltip features a highlighting circle around the icon of the Clock app. This is not simply a translucent overlay which disappears after click: The Clock icon can be clicked or even long-pressed at this moment, but other icons (outside the circle) are not accessible until the toolip disappears. Is all this behaviour custom made specifically for this purpose, or does some in-built facility exist?

[image]

Comment: I was just about to ask this question myself, although I was after the "balloon-tooltip" effect. Did you find a way of doing this? I'd prefer not to make my layout more complex for a feature that will be used once...

Answer (score 3):

It is just a translucent Dialog.

insert the below code in themes.xml in res folder

```
 <style name="Theme.TranparentDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

create the dialog over screen  to get a translucent effect/

```
Dialog dialog= new Dialog(context,  R.style.Theme_TutorialDialog);
```

dialog.show();

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, I've provided a more precise screenshot and updated my question a bit. Have a look at it please.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's using the [ShowcaseView Library](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView). See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129901/create-guided-tour-in-an-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

this view can be used to draw a transparent rectangle over the screen if used as background in the above Dialog.

```
public class WindowView extends View {
private static final int LOW_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = 19;

private static final int MEDIUM_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = 25;

private static final int HIGH_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT = 38;
Context mContext;

int mHeight, mWidth, mTop, mRight, mLeft, mBottom;
Rect mLeftRect, mRightRect, mTopRect, mBottomRect;

Rect mRect;
Paint mPaint;
View mAnchorView;
Paint mTempPaint1;

public WindowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public WindowView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public WindowView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mContext = context;
    initVariables();
}

boolean mReset = false;

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener mSimpleOnGestureListener;

private View getView() {
    return this;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mSimpleOnGestureListener == null) {
        mSimpleOnGestureListener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                if (mListener != null && e.getX() >= mRect.left
                        && e.getX() <= mRect.right && e.getY() >= mRect.top
                        && e.getY() <= mRect.bottom)
                    mListener.onClick(getView());
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
    if (mGestureDetector == null) {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(mContext,
                mSimpleOnGestureListener);
    }
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}

private void initVariables() {
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    mPaint.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(
            R.color.tut_transcluscent_bg));
    mRect = new Rect();

    mTempPaint1 = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mTempPaint1.setAlpha(64);
    mTempPaint1.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.WHITE,
            Mode.SRC_IN));
}

OnClickListener mListener;

public void setTransparentBackGroundColor(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
    invalidate();
}

@Override
public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener l) {
    mListener = l;
}

public View getAnchorView() {
    return mAnchorView;
}

float[] mPaddings;
Rect mAnchorRect;;

public void setAnchorView(View mView, Rect rect, float[] paddings) {
    mAnchorRect = rect;
    if (mAnchorRect == null)
        mAnchorView = mView;
    else
        mAnchorView = null;
    mPaddings = paddings;
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mAnchorView != null || mAnchorRect != null)
        initView();
    mReset = true;
}

boolean mFlagInvalid = false;
Handler mAnrHandler;

public void setHandler(Handler handler) {
    mAnrHandler = handler;
}

private int getStatusBarHeight() {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
            .getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);

    int statusBarHeight;

    switch (displayMetrics.densityDpi) {
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
        statusBarHeight = HIGH_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
        statusBarHeight = MEDIUM_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
        break;
    case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
        statusBarHeight = LOW_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
        break;
    default:
        statusBarHeight = MEDIUM_DPI_STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT;
    }
    return statusBarHeight;
}

public void initView() {

    mFlagInvalid = false;
    int top = 0, left = 0;
    if (mAnchorView != null) {
        top = mAnchorView.getTop();
        left = mAnchorView.getLeft();
        View temp = mAnchorView;
        int cnt = 0;
        try {
            while (((View) temp.getParent()).getId() != android.R.id.content) {
                temp = (View) temp.getParent();
                int scrolledHeight = 0;
                if (temp instanceof ScrollView) {
                    scrolledHeight = ((ScrollView) temp).getScrollY();
                }
                top = top + temp.getTop() - scrolledHeight;
                left = left + temp.getLeft();
                cnt++;
                if (cnt > 100) {
                    if (mAnrHandler != null)
                        mAnrHandler.sendEmptyMessage(9);
                    mFlagInvalid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mFlagInvalid = true;
            if (mAnrHandler != null)
                mAnrHandler.sendEmptyMessage(8);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        if (getContext()
                .getTheme()
                .resolveAttribute(
                        VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? android.R.attr.actionBarSize
                                : R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            int actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(
                    tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            top = top + actionBarHeight;
        }

    } else if (mAnchorRect != null) {
    }

    if (mFlagInvalid)
        init(20, 20, 50, 50);
    else {
        if (mAnchorRect != null) {
            init(mAnchorRect.bottom, mAnchorRect.right, mAnchorRect.left,
                    mAnchorRect.top);
        } else
            init(mAnchorView.getHeight(), mAnchorView.getWidth(), left, top);
    }
}

public void init(int height, int width, int left, int top) {
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
    mTop = top;
    mBottom = top + height;
    mLeft = left;
    mRight = left + width;

    mLeft = (int) (mLeft + mPaddings[0] * mWidth);
    mTop = (int) (mTop + mPaddings[1] * mHeight);
    mRight = (int) (mRight - mPaddings[2] * mWidth);
    mBottom = (int) (mBottom - mPaddings[3] * mHeight);
    mRect = new Rect(mLeft, mTop, mRight, mBottom);

    invalidate();
}

public Rect getAnchorRect() {
    return mRect;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    initOnceOnDraw();
    canvas.drawRect(mLeftRect, mPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(mTopRect, mPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(mRightRect, mPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(mBottomRect, mPaint);
    canvas.drawRect(mRect, mTempPaint1);
}

private void initOnceOnDraw() {
    if (mReset) {
        mReset = false;
        mTopRect = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), mRect.top);
        mLeftRect = new Rect(0, mRect.top, mRect.left, mRect.bottom);
        mRightRect = new Rect(mRect.right, mRect.top, getWidth(),
                mRect.bottom);
        mBottomRect = new Rect(0, mRect.bottom, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}}
```

The method setAnchorView() gives the view over which the overlay has to be drawn..

```
    mWindowView = (WindowView) mTutorialView
                            .findViewById(R.id.windowview_tutorial);
                        mWindowView.setTransparentBackGroundColor(backgroundColor);

                    mWindowView.setAnchorView(view, null, padding);
```

Hope this helps