# Animation for help overlay in Android Application

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

Is it possible to create animations to implement **help layout** for android applications as in the figure :
[image]

```
Desired Effect : The hand image should move and point to an icon.Then  an effect like ripple is created.
```

How could we implement animations like this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this by using the ShowCase view library from this github link, it works pretty well and it is very customizable

[ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Answer (score 1):

Follow this link :

http://www.xda-developers.com/create-holo-themed-demo-overlays-with-showcaseview/

or

refer this :

[Display overlay tooltip on the first run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18387715/display-overlay-tooltip-on-the-first-run)