# how to include application tutorials on first use xamarin.android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to deploy the app on play store then after a user downloads the app and opens it, the app will prompt some guide or tutorial per module or function to guide the user. Is there any easy way to do it ?

Note: It's okay if the tutorial prompts again if the user deletes the app and reinstall.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129901/create-guided-tour-in-an-android-app

Answer (score 2):

The most consistent way I've found is to use something like these [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) or [MaterialShowcaseView](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) to display the tutorial, then save that your user has already seen it using something like [Shared Preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html). Upon next opening, all you have to do is check the Shared Preferences again to see if the user has already seen that tutorial.

Comment: this is what the questioner is looking for

Answer (score 0):

The earlier way was to use a view pager with images of the tutorials and show it once using the concept of preferences. Now we can use various third party library like ShowcaseView to show the tutorials and using preference you can avoid it showing every time the user opens the application.

Answer (score 0):

You could install  [James Montemagnos Settings Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin). It can write persisting data to the AppData on your mobile device. You will then create a bool in the Settings.cs-File. As soon as the Tutorial is over, you set this bool to true and you only show this tutorial when the bool is false.